# reject HostKey: when deploying JAR with gradle ssh plugin

Tags: java, gradle, ssh, gradle-ssh-plugin

I am trying to upload jar with `Gradle` and used `Gradle` SSH plugin: https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/

Unfortunately, goal executed with error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deploy'.
> reject HostKey: SERVERIPADDRESS
```

How to fix?

I found that there is similar error with Ant SSH task and it can be fixed with trust = true setting. Unfortunately, I can't find appropriate option here.

I.e. apparently, I need to configure SSH client so that it accept host's ID.

Answer (score 18):

**Try this:**

```
 ssh.settings {
      knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
 }
```

P.S: Sorry for editing mistakes, new to S.O.F.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 4):

**Run**: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa server.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Explanation:
you have to add server SSH key info to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

To obtain ssh-info run command `ssh-keyscan -t rsa server.com`
and add its output to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you need to accept/validate the other server.
Another option for that would be to just connect to the server via ssh. Normally you will be asked to accept the server and the servers fingerprint will be added permanently to your known_hosts file.

Comment: how? without known_hosts, the plugin complains the file is not found

Comment: I guess if the file doesn't exist under your home directory in the .ssh folder you can just  create the file manually. Otherwise you can use the ssh-keyscan command as mentioned above (at least on a linux based system). See here for example: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-add-an-ssh-fingerprint-to-your-knownhosts-file-in-linux/